# How to define a range for an attribute in sql table?

Tags: sql

How to define(i.e. limit) a data within a certain range in SQL table?

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  a number(10),
  duration XXX        --how to define this time duration as from 0s to 10000s?
);
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases support the use of `CHECK` constraints.  So, if you want to represent an integer number of seconds between 0 and 10,000, then you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
  a number(10),
  duration int,
  constraint chk_duration check (duration between 1 and 10000)
);
```

Of course, the same logic holds if you want a floating or fixed point number instead.